# How to change the font size in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jqgrid

It is already running with the ui-lightness. How do I change the font size inside the grid?

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is an excellent post about this on the [jqGrid Forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/how-to-reduce-font-size-of-a-jqgrid/).

Essentially you can do what Mano suggests and modify the css file directly, or you can create your own in-line style if you need more flexibility. For example:

```
.ui-jqgrid {font-size:0.8em}
```

If you do create an inline style you may need to make it more specific to pick up grid rows:

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {font-size:0.8em}
```

Comment: sorry for the late late uptick. better late than never. i even forgotten why i asked that question. weird. hope this helps other people.

Answer (score 6):

The very first line in `ui.jqgrid.css` is this:

```
 .ui-jqgrid{position:relative;font-size:11px;}
```

Change the font-size to what you need.

Answer (score 3):

I recently did this for version 4.5.4 of the jqGrid, and had to override more than just the parent `.ui-jqgrid` selector. In this example, I wanted all text anywhere in the grid to be `12px` versus the default of `11px`:

```
/* Bump up the font-size in the grid */
.ui-jqgrid,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-input {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Note that this was done in a separate CSS file, not by directly editing the packaged CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

You can also format a specific grid column by referencing it in your custom css by the grid name and use the aria-describedby property to target the specific column.  For example:

`#Mygrid td[aria-describedby="Mygrid_myspecialcolumnname"]
{
font-size: 14px;
}`

You can read more about aria-describedby here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/ARIA1.html

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version - Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_4.8.2, inorder to change the font style of grid-row elements, just this one change worked for me - in ui.jqgrid.css

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgroup td {font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please remove this post - it is related to another product (jsgrid) and the below solution will confuses the users of jqGrid**

As of Sept 2021, the method that worked for me is:

```
.jsgrid table {font-size: XX; }
```

table {} also works, but for obvious reasons better to be more specific.

Alternately, .jsgrid td, or .jsgrid tr also works

Comment: Thee question is related to jqGrid not jsgrid, which is quite diffrent