# How to change font size and other style of jqgrid 4.15

Tags: free-jqgrid

Trying to update look and feel of jqgrid.

I am trying to increase the font size of the data in the grid as well as of the column header.

Here is my jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/4ga1ekh3/69/

Using the code at
[How to change the font size in jqGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677695/how-to-change-the-font-size-in-jqgrid)

```
.ui-jqgrid {font-size:0.8em}
```

But this did not work.

I would also like to know how to increase the font of the various fields when of the edit form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered here, I resolved this by using the below code:

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgroup td {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12px;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-th-column > div.ui-jqgrid-sortable {
font-size: 15px;
}

span.ui-jqgrid-cell-wrapper {
font-size: 16px;
}


td.jqgrid-rownum {
font-size: 15px;
}
```